# Tkinter Custom Widget rowconfigure missing argument 'index'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I wrote a custom widget which contains a Label, Entry and a Treeview. Now I want that custom widget to fill the frame I would like to place it in. I thought rowconfigure was the thing to go. So my code looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class CustomWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)        
        tk.Frame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)   

        self.Search_Text_Label = tk.Label(self, text="Search:",font=("Century Gothic",12))
        self.Search_Text_Label.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky='W', padx=10)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.entry.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky='W')
        self.entry.bind('<Return>',search)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        self.tree.state = "disabled"

        self.tree.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky='S', pady=0, padx=20)
```

But I get this error message:

> TypeError: grid_rowconfigure() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'index'

What do I have to change? And is this really the way to go?

Comment: It's bad design to have a widget configure its place in its parent. It makes the code hard to update, because if you change something in the parent you'll have to change something in all of the other classes that do this. The code that creates an instance of your custom widget should be responsible for placing it on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `rowconfigure` on the class `tk.Frame`. Instead, you should call it on your class instance, which is `self`, so:

```
self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

Also, if you want the Treeview to stretch vertically, you should use `sticky='NS'`.

Comment: I changed that, no changes. If I give my tk.Frame a background color I see that it is smaller as the frame in my main where I placed my custom widget. How do I get them to the same size?

Comment: What do you mean "no changes"? If you change these two things, you should not get an error anymore and the Treeview should stretch vertically. If you want more than that, you should clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: I got it now. I had to make the Custom widget placed in the Frame in my MainGUI sticky. After that it worked fine! Thank you!